# Recognizing the python objects while reading a csv file via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file, which has pythonlike objects in its column values stored as string, and when read via `pd.read_csv('IGGIN_PipeSegments.csv', sep=';', lineterminator='\n')`, these column values are stored as string objects:

```
df[['source_id', 'node_id']]
         source_id                        node_id
0    ['INET_PL_1']    ['INET_N_23', 'INET_N_295']
1    ['INET_PL_3']  ['INET_N_1460', 'INET_N_904']
2    ['INET_PL_5']    ['INET_N_317', 'INET_N_26']
3    ['INET_PL_7']    ['INET_N_36', 'INET_N_108']
4    ['INET_PL_9']   ['INET_N_36', 'INET_N_1653']
..             ...                            ...
957  ['NO_406790']         ['NO_N_45', 'NO_N_46']
958  ['NO_414837']          ['NO_N_7', 'NO_N_25']
959  ['NO_425280']         ['NO_N_47', 'NO_N_48']
960  ['NO_433996']         ['NO_N_49', 'NO_N_50']
961  ['NO_444927']         ['NO_N_51', 'NO_N_52']
[962 rows x 2 columns]

df['node_id'][0]
"['INET_N_23', 'INET_N_295']"
```

How ever I would like to store these values as (list `['INET_N_23', 'INET_N_295']` for example for the `df['node_id'][0]`) instead of `"['INET_N_23', 'INET_N_295']"`.

Is there a way to recognize columns values (as list for `df['node_id']`, as dict for `df['param']`) via pandas? or I should write a recognize function to understand both elements of the list. Create the list, and then add them into `node_id` column values?

**Note:**
CSV file is https://easyupload.io/zcypfu. There are also dict-like elements in the csv file:

```
df['param'][0]
"{'diameter_mm': 923.7925292425738, 'end_year': 2050, 'is_H_gas': 1.0, 'is_bothDirection': 0, 'lat_mean': 39.1412549, 'length_km': 151.1390654104781, 'long_mean': -2.5349646999999997, 'max_cap_M_m3_per_d': 45.51031743360152, 'max_pressure_bar': 75.0, 'num_compressor': 3.0, 'start_year': 1983, 'waterDepth_m': 292.0434688938135}"
```

Comment: Convert to list  -> `df.source_id = df.source_id.apply(ast.literal_eval)`  and then to fetch value `df.source_id.str[<Index_Number>]`??

Comment: @MichaelDelgado that will help for list. What about the dict-like objects?

Comment: did you try it? `ast.literal_eval` will also work on dicts - that answer should still do the trick

Comment: TY! @MichaelDelgado it works!